# How to make gamekit connection without needing both peers to press the same button

Tags: ios, xcode, p2p, gamekit

I'm trying to develop an app where I send the details of a contact to another device. I can connect the two devices but only if the same button on both devices is pressed.

My question is: Can I use gamekit to make the app listen for devices in the background so that the listening device doesn't have to press a button to allow the searching device to find it. So basically:

Searching Device(x): Presses Button -> Finds Other Device

Listening Device(y): Device x would like to connect with you. (without needing to press a button to make itself visible)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure I'm understanding your question completely, but you can make your app visible by setting the 'available' property of the GKSession object to true.

```
GKSession *session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"MyApp" displayName:@"Name" sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
session.delegate = self;
[session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:NULL];
session.available = YES;
```

Or maybe you're using the GKPicker to set up connections, and referring to the modal window that says "XX wants to connect"?

It is perfectly possible to silently auto-accept incoming connections. Take a look at the GKSessionDelegate protocol.

Basically, you do:

```
 - (void)session:(GKSession *)session didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer:(NSString *)peerID
{
    NSError *err;
    if (![session acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:&err])
        //Deal with error
}
```

Comment: I am trying to select which device to connect to using the GKPicker but I would like the second device to show the pop up "Device X would like to connect with you" without needing the second device to search aswell.... basically I want the second device to start listening automatically